# Universal Image Loader image scaling distortion

Tags: java, android, image, universal-image-loader

I have a `ListView` that presents a picture and some text on each row. The picture is loaded dynamically at run time using `Universal Image Loader`. It works, but the problem is that the pictures are not scaled correctly. I want them to be scaled to retain their original aspect ratio, but instead they are stretched to fill the square dimension of their container thereby distorting many of the images.

The listview adapter is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/my_img"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/coach_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The image gets loaded from a server at run time. This is the adapter class:

```
public class CoachAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> coach_list;
    private DisplayImageOptions doption=null;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener =null;

    public CoachAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> coach_list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, coach_list);

        this.context = context;
        this.coach_list = coach_list;

        doption=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.my_img)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.my_img)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.my_img)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(8))
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {
                        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 32, 32, false);
                    }
                })
                .build();
        animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_coach, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.coach_name);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        String coach_name = coach_list.get(position);

        // get the url string from the database
        Coach this_coach = myDB.getCoachFromName(coach_name);

        String coach_picture_url = this_coach.getCoachPictureURL();

        holder.text.setText(coach_name);
        holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        imageLoader.displayImage(url, holder.image, doption, animateFirstListener);

        return row;
    }

    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }
}
```

As I read the [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/630e580313ff683700bebffac178fb6f3a556f1e/library/src/main/java/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/DisplayImageOptions.java) docs, this is supposed scale the images based on what is specified in the XML file. I've tried `fitCenter` and `fitXY`. No matter what I specify, the image is always square. I've also verified that the dimensions of many of the original images are NOT square, so I know that the scaling distortion is happening here.

Any one see what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a fix?

Comment: No, not yet. I sort of moved on from this problem. I'll get back to it someday and if I resolve it, I'll post the solution. Sorry.